# Get query string values and pass to JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, query-string

I am trying to create my own custom breadcrumb, to do this I have to get the query string using PHP then pass it to my jQuery. So far I have been able to get the query string `keys/values` in a foreach loop then place them inside an input, which I can then get the values using jQuery but, my issue is that if I have multiple values for a single key like so;

```
?filter_style=bevelled-glass&filter_colour=amber,clear
```

What I retrieve is both values as one, but I need to be able to separate them. Here is my code and what I am retrieving;

Code;

```
<?php 
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
        echo '<input class="' . $key . '" type="text" value="' . $value . '" style="display: none;">';
    }
?>
```

output;

```
<input class="filter_style" type="text" value="bevelled-glass" style="display: none;">
<input class="filter_colour" type="text" value="amber,clear" style="display: none;">
```

What I want;

```
<input class="filter_style" type="text" value="bevelled-glass" style="display: none;">
<input class="filter_colour" type="text" value="amber" style="display: none;">
<input class="filter_colour" type="text" value="clear" style="display: none;">
```

Also is this the best way to pass this data to my jQuery or can I create some sort oJSONon object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explode each value to get an array of items from them and then loop and print.

```
<?php 
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
        $subarray = explode(",",$value);
        foreach($subarray as $subvalue)
        {
             echo '<input class="' . $key . '" type="text" value="' . $subvalue . '" style="display: none;">';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a ton about PHP, but from what I know about GET requests, you should be able to get the `amber,clear` as an array and break it out from there.  In **pseudocode**,

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($value is array) { 
        foreach ($val in $value) {
            <input class="' . $key . '" value="' . $val . '">
        }
    else {
        <input class="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '">
    }
}
```

I would be very surprised if that code ran as written, but that's what I do to get through this problem when developing in other languages.  Also, in my opinion, it's always better to use JSON wherever you can.

Comment: `if ($value is array) { ` this condition will never pass since he doesn't pass an array, he pass a string with comma's

Comment: yeah, I think the Sujit's answer is the right way in exact code

Comment: Yes, mine also tested and work fine, but downvoted, since always there's someone somewhere with the wrong privileges at the hand...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that's

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){

if(count(explode(',',$value))){

foreach(explode(',',$value) as $subvalue){

echo '<input class="' . $key . '" type="text" value="' . $subvalue . '" style="display: none;">';

}

}else{
echo '<input class="' . $key . '" type="text" value="' . $value . '" style="display: none;">';
}

}
```